# JSLint "JavaScript URL." error

Tags: javascript, url, jslint

JSLint is giving me a weird error. My code looks something like this:

```
{ reporter: 'mocha:Spec' }
```

and JSLint is throwing an error that just says:

```
JavaScript URL.
```

With the line number. Has anyone seen anything like that? What does it mean? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

JSLint checks for javascript URLs in your code and it does so with the following line

```
// javascript url
jx = /(?:javascript|jscript|ecmascript|vbscript|mocha|livescript)\s*:/i,
```

It assumes that `mocha:Spec` is a javascript url, like in `<a href="mocha:Spec">`